# How can I remove all missing values?

Tags: stata

How can I delete all missing values from my dataset? I work in Stata and have 7 variables.

How can I remove all missing values, in order to keep only observations that have values for all variables and all the years that I want to use?

For example, my dataset contains roughly 6000 rows, and one variable is *employees*; some rows have 0 employees, which is impossible, I need to remove these full rows (so all the other variable values in that same row too...)

Comment: You should show an explicit variable and at least attempt some code.

Comment: ... an explicit data example ...

Answer (score 0):

Zero does not count as missing in Stata. But a specific criterion for that problem is

```
drop if employees == 0
```

Otherwise

```
egen nmissing = rowmiss(*) 
drop if nmissing 
drop nmissing
```